How to get anacron daily to run at specific time
I am using Fedora and anacron to schedule regular daily maintenance tasks. The problem is that I cannot get the jobs run at the time I want - 00:05.
My /etc/anacrontab file:
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=<redacted>
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=0
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=0-23

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
@daily          0       cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7                       25              cron.weekly    nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        45      cron.monthly    nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly

My /etc/crontab file (if it is relevant):
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=<redacted>

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed

10 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
5  0    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts /etc/cron.daily )
20 1    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts /etc/cron.weekly )
25 1    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts /etc/cron.monthly )

What am I doing wrong?
